# XRegExp replace

Tags: javascript, regex, xregexp

I'm trying to do some string manipulation on some words that may or may not have unicode characters in them.

Here's my code:

```js
var regex = XRegExp("(\\P{L}+)", "gui");
var s = 'no sea demásiado tarde';
var ret = XRegExp.replace(s, regex, "<span>$1</span>");

console.log(ret);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.1.1/xregexp-all.min.js"></script>
```

But the words are not getting wrapped by the span tags as expected. How come?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are wrapping non-letters with `\\P{L}+` as `\P{L}` matches any character other than a Unicode letter.

Use `"\\p{L}+"` pattern and replace with `<span>$&</span>` (the `$&` backreference stands for a whole match).

```js
var regex = XRegExp("\\p{L}+", "gui");
var s = 'no sea demásiado tarde';
var ret = XRegExp.replace(s, regex, "<span>$&</span>");

console.log(ret);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.1.1/xregexp-all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Now I'm embarrassed... Thank you